# How to use Powershell to run a exe with a wildcard as the directory keeps changing with each install

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I am attempting to run a .exe file for an app which is installed but requires to be activated. This would be a fairly easy process but the directory with .exe changes name slightly with each install. For example a number is added to each folder after the install (Different devices have different numbers)  e.g. test1 and then test2. How could I use a wild card to target the folder as it changes?

Example code:

Start-Process -FilePath "\C:\ProgramData\app*/test.exe"

Please note: the app is not real, this is just for display purposes.

Comment: Have a look at [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: I've never heard of that cmdlet @zett42, pretty neat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path seems to be incorrect. Wildcards should work in PowerShell. For example, the below wildcard works for me in PowerShell 5.0:

[image]

Try running `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\app*\test.exe"`